# Is there an function for resizing images in a slideshow

Tags: php, html, css, slideshow, w3.css

I'm building a website for my local association we have a few sponsors who's logo i would like to display in a slideshow. It's been a while since a builded a website for the last time so i decided to just take a head start with a w3.css template and also use the w3.css solutions for the slideshow. it's working fine of course. except the logo's are not of the same size and quality. Right now the slideshow doesn't resize the images, but i can't figure out how to do that.

so my slideshow is this:

```
<div class="slideshow-container w3-half w3-content w3-display-container" id="Slideshow">
  <img class="Slideshow-Sponsors" src="images/Sponsors/ABS.png">
  <img class="Slideshow-Sponsors" src="images/Sponsors/Kirkels.png">
  <img class="Slideshow-Sponsors" src="images/Sponsors/Meneerkes.png">
  <img class="Slideshow-Sponsors" src="images/Sponsors/Dierx.png">

  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
</div>
```

the javascript is plain simple atm:

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("Slideshow-Sponsors");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
}
```

Some pictures are high quality (3.404x1.056) while others are of bad quality (200x200). I would like to have just one size, upscale the smaller ones and crop the bigger ones. at last i want to center the images that looks a bit better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to find your answer here:

[W3.css Images Doc](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_images.asp)

About halfway down the page there is a section called "Responsive Images", I believe that has examples of what you are looking for.

Comment: sounds like you have another css value for height that is causing the height not to automatically adjust with the width. You could change it to width:100%;height:100% and see if that will work. if not add height:100% !important. !important will override any other css values of that type on an element but I would only use it as a last resort.

Comment: Well i added height:350px to the images now they have all the same height on a desktop that works for me. not the best result but it works, ive not been able to test it on a mobile device but i think that will not be that nice. When i add 100% nothing changes which isnt strange because that doenst change the height of the image

Comment: You could also try setting min-height to 100%.